# Entering data into SQLite

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlite, serial-port

I am working with a project and started a small project to get some data over the Serial. The data comes over the Serial, but nothing gets added to the Database. The tables get created, but not the actual data gets pushed. Something is going wrong there.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import serial
import time

import sqlite3
import os
from datetime import datetime

conn = sqlite3.connect("elements78.db") # or use :memory: to put it in RAM

cursor = conn.cursor()
sql_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'elements78.db')
needs_creation = not os.path.exists(sql_file) 
db_connection = sqlite3.connect(sql_file)
db_connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

# create a table
if needs_creation:
    print 'Creating initial database...'
    cursor = db_connection.cursor()

    db_connection.commit()
    print 'Database created.'

cursor.executescript("""
                    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS elements;
                    CREATE TABLE elements (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name, date CURDATE )
                    """)

#enter your device file
arddev = '/dev/tty.usbmodem621'
baud = 9600

#setup - if a Serial object can't be created, a SerialException will be raised.
while True:
    try:
        ser = serial.Serial(arddev, baud)

        #break out of while loop when connection is made
        break
    except serial.SerialException:
        print 'waiting for device ' + arddev + ' to be available'
        time.sleep(3)

#read lines from serial device
count = 0
while count < 5:

    element = ser.readline().strip('\n')
    count = count + 1
    datestamp = datetime.now()
    print 'received the element: ' + element 
    print datestamp

    cursor.execute('insert into elements(Name) values("%s")'%(element))


allentries = []
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM elements')

allentries=cursor.fetchall()

print allentries
```

Comment: maybe that could give you some advise http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/

Comment: I *really really really* advice you to use `sqlalchemy` package

Comment: Good advice from Jakub M, sqlalchemy will make your life much easier in this situation and it's an ORM too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding

```
db_connection.commit()
```

after your INSERT statements.